# Pass a type parameter to be used as argument LabelledGeneric

Tags: scala, shapeless, labelled-generic

I'm trying to parametrize a method that needs to work on a generic type `A` for which a `LabelledGeneric` can be retrieved. Here's the naive approach

```
case class Foo(bar: String, baz: Boolean)

def params[A](a: A) = {
  val lbl = LabelledGeneric[A]
  val keys = Keys[lbl.Repr].apply
  ...
}

val myThingy = params(Foo)
```

Of course, the underlying macro complains. It doesn't know enough about `A`:

> type A is not a class or trait

---

So, I tried to have the `LabelledGeneric` inferred

```
def params[A](a: A)(implicit lbl: LabelledGeneric[A]) = {
  val keys = Keys[lbl.Repr].apply
  ...
}
```

this seems to work, but the `Repr` type is not known to be an `HList` anymore

> type arguments [lbl.Repr] do not conform to method apply's type parameter bounds [L <: shapeless.HList]

---

Ok, let's try to be more precise

```
def params[A, Repr <: HList](a: A)(implicit lbl: LabelledGeneric.Aux[A, Repr]) = {
  val keys = Keys[lbl.Repr].apply
  ...
}
```

Now, `Repr` is definitely an `HList`, but still `Keys` cannot resolve its implicits

> could not find implicit value for parameter values: shapeless.ops.record.Values[lbl.Repr]

---

Final attempt, let's try to have everything I need computed implicitly

```
def params[A, Repr <: HList](a: A)(implicit
  lbl: LabelledGeneric.Aux[A, Repr],
  kk: Keys[Repr]
) = {
  val keys = kk.apply
  ...
}
```

Still no luck, apparently the first implicit cannot be resolved at call site

> could not find implicit value for parameter lbl: shapeless.LabelledGeneric.Aux[example.Main.Foo.type,Repr]
>
> [error]   params(Foo)

Clearly all of this machinery works, when dealing directly with the specific type, e.g.

```
val lbl = LabelledGeneric[Foo]
val keys = Keys[lbl.Repr].apply
// no problem
```

I'm clearly missing the needed set of refinements on my type in the method signature, but I can get my head around what's going on here. Any idea?

Comment: Can you please tag this with the language used?

Comment: @GabrielePetronella nice explain, I'm a little bit disappointed to find this SO post after pass half a day to find what you are already explained

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The last variant with everything computed implicitly works for me,

```
scala> import shapeless._, ops.record._
import shapeless._
import ops.record._

scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

def params[A, Repr <: HList](a: A)
  (implicit lbl: LabelledGeneric.Aux[A, Repr], kk: Keys[Repr]) = {
  val keys = kk.apply
  keys
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

params: ...

scala> case class Foo(bar: String, baz: Boolean)
defined class Foo

scala> params(foo)
res0: ... = 'bar :: 'baz :: HNil
```

(result types elided for readability).

Comment: oh, silly me. The mistake was passing the `Foo` constructor, rather than an instance. Is there a way to drive type inference using the `Foo` apply method instead? I'd like to achieve something like `params(Foo)`

Comment: Having `params(Foo)` work is possible, but fairly awkward. In context, is `params(Foo)` really much better than `params[Foo]`?

Comment: I'm working on a custom spray routing 
 directive, so ultimately I will need to use the 'as' method with as(Foo) in my implementation, that's why I need to pass the constructor down